# How can I draw a box in C++ using Unicode?

Tags: c++, unicode

I am trying to make a little RPG in C++ with Unicode but I can't even make a simple box. I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void PrintLevel();

string lvl[5][4] {
        {"\u250f", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2513"},
        {"\u2503", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u2503"},
        {"\u2503", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u2503"},
        {"\u2503", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u2503"},
        {"\u2517", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u251B"}
    };

int main() {
  PrintLevel();
}

void PrintLevel() {
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<4; j++) {
            cout << lvl[i][j];
            if(j == 3) {
                cout << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it draws this

[image: currentbox]

How can I get it to draw a proper box?

Comment: Don't use stdio as it's too dependent on rendering by the terminal and what font the user chooses.

Comment: Seems like its printing fine https://onlinegdb.com/B1h47uzhf

Comment: @Mgetz I'm not?

Comment: @KeineLust It wasn't edited to use `iostream`, I've always used it.

Comment: @JordanBaron `cout` and `cin` are linked to C stdio, hence the names `cout` and `cin`

Comment: @Mgetz Then what would I use? I thought `cout` was the standard?

Comment: @Mgetz so what? is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: @JordanBaron if you want consistent layout across machines you'll need to use a console rendering library like ncurses. Alternatively you can just specify which font they need to set their console to so they can play the game but many people have very specific console fonts they prefer

Comment: Use a *monospace* font in your terminal.

Comment: Maybe consider using `wcout` instead of `cout` for unicode output.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\u2500` for horizontal line, 2501 is the heavy one which is larger than a single space.

Or you may use `\u3000` ideographic space to replace 0020 (not sure it work correctly in every font but looks like ok).

Comment: Well, whether 2501 is larger than a single space or not really depends on the font: https://ideone.com/DfPQxB  https://wandbox.org/permlink/Xwc3klnzc4U84C8C  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

Answer (score 0):

So there's just an alignment issue with the right side of the box right? It looks like it should be printing correctly, so maybe try adding one more column of spaces? Also, you can skip the if statement for the newline and place `cout  << endl;` after the inner loop's end bracket:

```
    for (...) {
        for (...) {

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```