# How do I use ncurses to render Unicode the same way across different terminals?

Tags: c++, unicode, ncurses

I was told to use `ncurses` to render a unicode level in my program by user MGetz in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864439/how-can-i-draw-a-box-in-c-using-unicode/49865069#49865069) post. So, I have updated my code to use `ncurses`, but it still renders differently in different terminals. I compiled my code using `g++ file.cpp -o file -std=c++11 -lncursesw` Speaking of my code, here it is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

void PrintLevel();

string lvl[9][11] {
        {"\u250f", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2513"},
        {"\u2503", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u2503"},
        {"\u2503", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u2503"},
        {"\u2503", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u2503"},
        {"\u2503", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u2503"},
        {"\u2503", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u2503"},
        {"\u2503", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u2503"},
        {"\u2503", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u0020", "\u2503"},
        {"\u2517", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u2501", "\u251B"}
    };

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    PrintLevel();
    getch();
    endwin();
}

void PrintLevel() {
    for(int i = 0; i<9; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<11; j++) {
            printw(lvl[i][j].c_str());
            if(j == 10) {
                printw("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    refresh();
}
```

Oh, and just for reference, I am using Codenvy as I only have access to my school Chromebook. Trying it on another Codenvy-like service, Codeanywhere, the Unicode doesn't even render properly, I get this:

[image: codeanywhere output]

Answer (score 0):

Offhand:

- since the screen is showing the replacement character (that odd-looking question mark), one would assume the terminal is setup for UTF-8, but
- you're calling `setlocale` to use the locale settings, but don't mention what they are (`LC_ALL`, etc., as shown by the **`locale`** command), and
- didn't mention if you're compiling/linking with ***ncursesw*** (expected) or ***ncurses***.

If you have both the wrong locale settings and linking with ***ncurses***, it could look like that picture.

Comment: I updated my post to show the compile command. How would I set the locale to use UTF-8?

Comment: It's environment variables (but depends on what locale support you have installed).